# How to create a has_many relationship between two models, with several models in between? (Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What I'd like to do is join one model to another using two intermediary models in between..Here's the abstraction:

```
Country has_many Companies
Company has_many Buildings, Company belongs_to Country
Building has_many Rooms, Building belongs_to Company
Room belongs_to Building
```

I want to be able to do Country.first.rooms, so I thought the Country model would be as simple as:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
  has_many :buildings, :through=>:companies
  has_many :rooms, :through=>:buildings
end
```

However, this tries to generate SQL like:
SELECT * FROM `rooms`  INNER JOIN `buildings` ON `rooms`.building_id = `building`.id    WHERE ((`building`.country_id = 1))

Obviously, building.country_id does not exist. How do I get around this?

Comment: What's your Rails (specifically ActiveRecord) version?

Answer (score 1):

The built in association methods won't help you here. You need to build the query explicitly using joins:

```
class Country - ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :companies
    has_many :buildings, :through=>:companies

    def rooms
      Room.all :joins => { :building => { :company => :country } }, :conditions => { "countries.id" => id }
    end

end
```

This will require the belongs_to associations to be set up on the Building and Company models

Comment: With that, I get an error saying:
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'country' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?

I'm guessing it's because "building", which is one model removed from country (they are associated by "Company", which explicitly belongs to a Country) is only implicitly related to country.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [nested has many through](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through/tree/master)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible after Rails 3.1. The below code works for me. It's important to specify the `has_many` at each level.

```
class Country
  has_many :companies
  has_many :buildings, through: :companies
  has_many :rooms, through: buildings
end

class Company
  has_many :buildings
end

class Building
  has_many :rooms
end

class Room
end
```